# Perl - When <%method PREPARE> gets called

Tags: perl, prepare, mason

I am new to Perl Mason.

I came across this with the suggestion that service calls should be put inside PREPARE block. But when I placed my service calls inside it, seems like the code inside it is never getting executed itself.

```
<%method PREPARE>
```

Kindly suggest what is the above block for and its usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the **Mason Manual**:

> The base component class, Mason::Component, has but a few built-in
>   methods: handle, render, wrap, main, m, and cmeta.
>
> The main method contains the mix of HTML and Perl in the main part of
>   the component.
>
> You can add other methods that output HTML via the  section;
>   these methods automatically have access to $self and $m.
>
> ```
> <%method leftcol>
>   <table><tr>
>     <td><% $foo %></td>
>     ...
>   </tr></table>
> </%method>
>
> ...
>
> <% # call leftcol method and insert HTML here %>
> <% $.leftcol %>
> ```

Which means you are declaring a method named `PREPARE` without any argument lists by `<%method PREPARE>` and after writing the method body you will end it using `</%method>`.

And, later somewhere you will call it using  `<% $.PREPARE %>`.For more info refer the [Mason Manual](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.24/lib/Mason/Manual/Components.pod#METHODS).